# Can someone explain me exactly what the below definition means in the C standard about directives

Tags: c, directive, non-printing-characters

What i exactly need to know is what characters are allowed before the start of a directive as we all know we can have **new line** characters and **whitespace** characters before the start of a directive **before ( # )** now i read the C standard about this and found out the following definition explaining this:

> A preprocessing directive consists of a sequence of preprocessing tokens that satisfies the following constraints: The first token in the sequence is a # preprocessing token that (at the start of translation phase 4) is either the first character in the source file (optionally after white space containing no new-line characters) or that follows white space containing at least one new-line character.
> ["C standard - read here the definition"](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10p2)

now what i exactly need to know is:
what do they mean by

> (optionally after whitespace **containing no "new-line" characters**) or that follows whitespace **containing at least one "new-line" character**

the

> **containing no new-line characters**

and

> **containing at least one new-line character**

is what i don't understand in the above definition i need to know what that exactly means and i need to know

> *where new-line characters can occur is it before # token or after # token the C standard haven't stated where new-line characters can occur **(it only states "containing no new-line characters" and "containing atleast one new-line character")** **(it haven't stated whether where new-line characters can occur in this case before # token or after # token)** even though it have stated where whitespace characters can occur(before # token) in the above situation*

Comment: That is C-speak for first non-whitespace character in file or first non-whitespace character in a line. Which boils down to the `#` has the be the first non-whtiespace character on any line in the file to provide a macro definition or pre-processing directive.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you. can you tell me what they mean from that i mean where actually a **new-line character can occur**

Comment: In C and `'\n'` is whitespace and largely ignored. However, when you are talking about pre-processing tokens or macro definition, they have to appear as the first non-whitespace character in the line. So that part of the standard is just saying if it's not the first line, you have to have a newline character before the `'#'`. Otherwise, the are largely ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this all basically means is that either `#` is at the start of a line or there is only whitespace before `#` on a given line.

This part:

> either the first character in the source file (optionally after white space containing no new-line characters)

Allows for whitespace before `#` if it's on the first line of the file, while this part:

> or that follows white space containing at least one new-line character.

Allows for whitespace before `#` on any subsequent line.

For example:

```
  #include <stdio.h>   // spaces before the first line
  #include <stdlib.h>  // spaces before another line, i.e, spaces and newline before a token
int x;   #include <string.h> // not allowed, other tokens preceed on same line
```

Comment: Thank You N can you explain me where actually a new line character can occur according to the description of the C standard before # or after # and its not clear what they have stated in the C standard

Comment: @user13104441 Newlines can appear before a `#`.  They can also appear after a complete preprocessor directive.